# How do I mask only the output (labelled data). I don't have any problem in input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, masking

I have so many Nan values in my output data and I padded those values with zeros. Please don't suggest me to delete Nan or impute with any other no. I want  model to skip those nan positions.

example:

```
x = np.arange(0.5, 30)
x.shape = [10, 3]

x = [[ 0.5  1.5  2.5]
 [ 3.5  4.5  5.5]
 [ 6.5  7.5  8.5]
 [ 9.5 10.5 11.5]
 [12.5 13.5 14.5]
 [15.5 16.5 17.5]
 [18.5 19.5 20.5]
 [21.5 22.5 23.5]
 [24.5 25.5 26.5]
 [27.5 28.5 29.5]]

y = np.arange(2, 10, 0.8)

y.shape = [10, 1] 

y[4, 0] = 0.0

y[6, 0] = 0.0

y[7, 0] = 0.0

y = [[2. ]
[2.8]
[3.6]
[4.4]
[0. ]
[6. ]
[0. ]
[0. ]
[8.4]
[9.2]]
```

I expect keras deep learning model to predict zeros for 5th, 7th and 8th row as similar to the padded value in 'y'.

Comment: Use this sample code to mask labels `tensor = [0, 1, 2, 3]`
`mask = np.array([True, False, True, False])
tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)`. Thanks!